# xsd.exe generated c# with multiple elements in an array

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a set of XML schema files provided to me. I cannot changed the XML as these will be updated on occasion. I am using xsd.exe to convert the schema files to generated c# code. I cannot use any third party tools. Part of one of the XML schema files appears as such:

```
<xs:complexType name="LocationType">
  <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:element name="LocNum" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="City" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="State" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

When converted to c#, I get a result such as this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://abcxyz.com")]
public partial class LocationType
{

    private object[] itemsField;

    private ItemsChoiceType[] itemsElementNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Address", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("City", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("LocNum", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Longitude", typeof(decimal), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("State", typeof(LocationTypeState), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get { return this.itemsField; }
        set { this.itemsField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName
    {
        get { return this.itemsElementNameField; }
        set { this.itemsElementNameField = value; }
    }
}
```

Since these all get generated to partial classes, I am free to add additional code. I need to be able to read/set the individual properties, such as Name, Address, City, etc.

I need to be able to serialize these objects to match the schema.

Is there a way in c# to create a public property that will read or set the value in the Items array at the proper sequence, etc.? ie:

```
public partial class LocationType
{
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            // code here to return the correct Items[] element
        }
        set
        {
            // code here to set the correct Items[] element
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What that schema says is that if some outer type contains an element of type `LocationType`, one would expect to find inside *either*

1) A sub-element `<LocNum>`, OR

2) These sub-elements in sequence: `<Name>`, `<Address>`, `<City>` and `<State>`.

Thus the data here is polymorphic, even though it isn't being explicitly modeled as such in the c# classes generated by xsd.exe.  This sort of makes sense -- a location might be specified explicitly, or indirectly as a look-up in a table.

When deserializing a polymorphic sequence like this, `XmlSerializer` puts each element it finds in the array field corresponding to the elements in the sequence, in this case the array `Items`.  In addition, there should be another corresponding array field identified by the [`XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, in this case `ItemsElementName`.  The entries in this array must needs be in 1-1 correspondence with the `Items` array.  It records the name of the element that was deserialized in each index of the `Items` array, by way of the `ItemsChoiceType` enumeration, whose enum names must match the names in the [`XmlElementAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes decorating the `Items` array.  This allows the specific choice of polymorphic data to be known.

Thus, to round out the implementation of your `LocationType` class, you will need to determine whether a given `LocationType` is direct or indirect; fetch various properties out; and for each type (direct or indirect), set all required data.

Here is a prototype of that.  (You didn't include the definition for `LocationTypeState` in your question, so I'm just treating it as a string):

```
public partial class LocationType
{
    public LocationType() { }

    public LocationType(string locNum)
    {
        SetIndirectLocation(locNum);
    }

    public LocationType(string name, string address, string city, string state)
    {
        SetDirectLocation(name, address, city, state);
    }

    public bool IsIndirectLocation
    {
        get
        {
            return Array.IndexOf(ItemsElementName, ItemsChoiceType.LocNum) >= 0;
        }
    }

    public string Address { get { return (string)XmlPolymorphicArrayHelper.GetItem(Items, ItemsElementName, ItemsChoiceType.Address); } }

    public string LocNum { get { return (string)XmlPolymorphicArrayHelper.GetItem(Items, ItemsElementName, ItemsChoiceType.LocNum); } }

    // Other properties as desired.

    public void SetIndirectLocation(string locNum)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(locNum))
            throw new ArgumentException();
        object[] newItems = new object[] { locNum };
        ItemsChoiceType [] newItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType [] { ItemsChoiceType.LocNum };
        this.Items = newItems;
        this.ItemsElementName = newItemsElementName;
    }

    public void SetDirectLocation(string name, string address, string city, string state)
    {
        // In the schema, "City" is mandatory, others are optional.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
            throw new ArgumentException();
        List<object> newItems = new List<object>();
        List<ItemsChoiceType> newItemsElementName = new List<ItemsChoiceType>();
        if (name != null)
        {
            newItems.Add(name);
            newItemsElementName.Add(ItemsChoiceType.Name);
        }
        if (address != null)
        {
            newItems.Add(address);
            newItemsElementName.Add(ItemsChoiceType.Address);
        }
        newItems.Add(city);
        newItemsElementName.Add(ItemsChoiceType.City);
        if (state != null)
        {
            newItems.Add(state);
            newItemsElementName.Add(ItemsChoiceType.State);
        }
        this.Items = newItems.ToArray();
        this.ItemsElementName = newItemsElementName.ToArray();
    }
}

public static class XmlPolymorphicArrayHelper
{
    public static TResult GetItem<TIDentifier, TResult>(TResult[] items, TIDentifier[] itemIdentifiers, TIDentifier itemIdentifier)
    {
        if (itemIdentifiers == null)
        {
            Debug.Assert(items == null);
            return default(TResult);
        }
        Debug.Assert(items.Length == itemIdentifiers.Length);
        var i = Array.IndexOf(itemIdentifiers, itemIdentifier);
        if (i < 0)
            return default(TResult);
        return items[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's the final solution we came up with that leverages when I learned from the original answer. This static class is used to get and set the appropriate properties.

```
public static class XmlPolymorphicArrayHelper
{
    public static TResult GetItem<TIDentifier, TResult>(TResult[] items, TIDentifier[] itemIdentifiers, TIDentifier itemIdentifier)
    {
        if (itemIdentifiers == null)
        {
            return default(TResult);
        }
        var i = Array.IndexOf(itemIdentifiers, itemIdentifier);
        return i < 0 ? default(TResult) : items[i];
    }

    public static void SetItem<TIDentifier, TResult>(ref TResult[] items, ref TIDentifier[] itemIdentifiers, TIDentifier itemIdentifier, TResult value)
    {
        if (itemIdentifiers == null)
        {
            itemIdentifiers = new[] { itemIdentifier };
            items = new[] { value };

            return;
        }

        var i = Array.IndexOf(itemIdentifiers, itemIdentifier);
        if (i < 0)
        {
            var newItemIdentifiers = itemIdentifiers.ToList();
            newItemIdentifiers.Add(itemIdentifier);
            itemIdentifiers = newItemIdentifiers.ToArray();

            var newItems = items.ToList();
            newItems.Add(value);
            items = newItems.ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            items[i] = value;
        }

    }
}
```

And then call them from the partial class like this:

```
public partial class LocationType
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)XmlPolymorphicArrayHelper.GetItem(Items, ItemsElementName, ItemsChoiceType.Address);
        }
        set
        {
            XmlPolymorphicArrayHelper.SetItem(ref this.itemsField, ref this.itemsElementNameField, ItemsChoiceType.Address, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This sets/creates the appropriate member on the Items array and I can use this for the multiple classes that implement this pattern.